# Not getting correct result once columns are assigned to a variable and used in a simple query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to assign `column names` to a `variable` and use that `variable in SQL query` but I am not getting expected result.

Table:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
-------- -------- --------
1        1        ab
2        2        bc
3        1        bc
4        5        xy
```

Query - 1 (Works fine):

```
DECLARE @colCount BIGINT, @uniqColCount BIGINT, @result VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @colCount = COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
SELECT @uniqColCount = COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT column_1, column_2 AS ColumnCount FROM TestTable) AS ColumnCount

PRINT @colCount
PRINT @uniqColCount

   IF(@colCount = @uniqColCount)
     BEGIN
       SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM TestTable
     END
   ELSE
       PRINT 'false'
```

Result:

```
4
4
column_1 column_2
-------- --------
1        1
2        2
3        1
4        5
```

Query - 2 (Not Working as expected):

```
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(50), @colCount BIGINT, @uniqColCount BIGINT, @result VARCHAR(max)
SET @columnName = 'column_1, column_2'
SELECT @colCount = COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
SELECT @uniqColCount = COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT @columnName AS ColumnCount FROM TestTable) AS ColumnCount

PRINT @colCount
PRINT @uniqColCount

    IF(@colCount = @uniqColCount)
     BEGIN
       SELECT @columnName FROM TestTable
     END
   ELSE
       PRINT 'false'
```

Result:

```
4
1
false
```

Columns would be dynamic so I am trying this approach. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterise column name like that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT @columnName AS ColumnCount FROM TestTable
```

will just return a single row with the string value "column_1, column_2" (as long as TestTable contains at least one row).

You would need to use string concatenation and dynamic SQL for this - [beware of SQL injection](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you could assign column or table values as variables without using dynamic SQL..  but this opens the door to SQL injection...

```
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(50), @colCount BIGINT, @uniqColCount BIGINT, @result VARCHAR(max)
SET @columnName = 'column_1, column_2'
SELECT @colCount = COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
SELECT @uniqColCount = COUNT(*) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT @columnName AS ColumnCount FROM TestTable) AS ColumnCount

PRINT @colCount
PRINT @uniqColCount

    IF(@colCount = @uniqColCount)
     BEGIN
       EXEC sp_executeSQL concat('SELECT ', @columnName, ' FROM TestTable')
     END
   ELSE
       PRINT 'false'
```

Comment: I getting `Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT '.` error in `EXEC sp_executeSQL('SELECT ' + @columnName + ' FROM TestTable')` when I tried to run your given query.

Comment: `Exec sp_executeSQL 'SELECT column_1, Column_2 FROM testTable'` byitself works right? (got rid of ()'s)

Comment: Ya that is working but if I do `EXEC sp_executeSQL 'SELECT '+ @columnName + ' FROM TestTable'` then it throws error which is `Incorrect syntax near '+'.` don't know why

Comment: odd thought + was sql server concat... so try `sp_executeSQL concat('SELECT ', @columnName, ' FROM testTable')` note spaces after select and before FROM  assumes @columnName is formatted correctly 'column_1, column_2' and fields exist in testTable.

Comment: Well @columnName is formatted correctly and they do exists in testTable but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: let me look for some other approaches. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I used following approach to get expected results.

Query:

```
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(MAX), @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX), @colCountSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @uniqColCountSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @colCountOutput bigint, @uniqColCountOutput bigint 

SET @columnName = 'Column_1, Column_2, Column_3' 
SET @tableName = 'TestTable'

SET @colCountSQL = 'SELECT @colCountOutput = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tableName
print @colCountSQL

SET @uniqColCountSQL = 'SELECT @uniqColCountOutput = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ' + @columnName + ' FROM ' + @tableName + ') as ColumnCount' 
print @uniqColCountSQL

--uniqColCountSQL query will have dynamic columns.

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @colCountSQL, N'@colCountOutput BIGINT OUTPUT', @colCountOutput OUTPUT
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @uniqColCountSQL, N'@uniqColCountOutput BIGINT OUTPUT', @uniqColCountOutput OUTPUT

 IF( @colCountOutput = @uniqColCountOutput ) 
     BEGIN 
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) 
         SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columnName + ' FROM ' + @tableName
        EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
     END 
    ELSE 
     PRINT 'Selected column values are not unique'
```

Expected Result:

```
SELECT @colCountOutput = COUNT(*) FROM TestTable
SELECT @uniqColCountOutput = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column_1, Column_2, Column_3 FROM TestTable) as ColumnCount

Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
-------- -------- --------
1        2        ab
1        3        bc
3        4        cd
```